# C program to find percentage

Tags: c

I have a very simple program. I need to write a program that reads two integers (wins, losses). Call the two functions by passing the two numbers. Display the winning and losing percents. I wrote a code, but it didn't calculate and display the percentage. Need some help.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double Win (double winns);
double Loss (double losses);

int main() {
    int num1, num2, total;
    double winns, losses, sum1, sum2;
    printf("Enter the number of wins: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter the number of losses: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    total = num1 + num2;
    winns = (num1/total)/100;
    losses = (num2/total)/100;
    sum1 = Win(winns);
    sum2 = Loss(losses);

    printf("The team's winning percent for the years was: %.2f\n", sum1);
    printf("The team's losig percent for the years was: %.2f\n", sum2);

    return 0;
}

double Win (double winns){
   return (winns);
}

double Loss (double losses){
   return (losses);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of having a function with one parameter that just returns the argument passed to it?

Comment: You're doing integer arithmetic, which is going to round all fractions down to 0. You need to cast the numbers to float before dividing. Also, you convert a fraction to percent by _multiplying_ by 100, not dividing.

Comment: What did you input?  What did it output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert int to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530209/convert-int-to-float)

Comment: Also your formula for percentage is wrong...It should be (var/ total)*100

Comment: Is there a definitive resource we should link to for problems of `float=int/int`?

Answer (score 4):

1. When you divide integer by integer, you will get integer. In your case it will be 0, because `num1` is less than `total`. You need to cast one of them to double.
2. You need to multiply by 100, not divide to get percents.
3. I don't see the reason of creating `Win` and `Loss` here - you've already got your answers in `winns` and `losses`.
4. Why 'winns' with double n???

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

First of all, you should be casting num1, num2 and/or total to double.  Otherwise you'll be performing integer division and the result will always be zero.

Second problem: you need to multply by 100 to get a percentage, not divide.

Third problem: the %f format specifier expects a float, but you gave it a double.  sum1 and sum2 need to be casted to floats.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to pass double-type values to format specifiers expecting floats.