# Am I dividing in the right way in C?

Tags: c, function, types, division, cs50

I need to apply a formula to three variables. Some of the operations (divisions) give me a 0 instead of the proper number. So I get a different result from what I expected from the formula.

I think that the problem is related to the way C manages data types and their remainders. For this reason, I tried to transform int variables into float variables or to round the numbers that I divided. But all of this is still not working and I'm not able to understand what I'm missing.

Could you please have a look at my code and let me know where is the mistake? 
Thanks

```
double grade(int lc, int wc, int sc)
{
    wc = (float)wc;
    lc = (float)lc;
    sc = (float)sc;
    float L = round((wc/100)/lc);
    float S = round((wc/100)/sc);
    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    return index;
}
```

Comment: I suspect if you did it like they do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530209/how-to-convert-int-to-float-in-c), it should work. But currently you're storing it back in `wc`, which causes another conversion back to int. Try `float wc_new = (float)wc;` and using `wc_new` in the computation. If it works, I'll write that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

```
wc = (float)wc;
lc = (float)lc;
sc = (float)sc;
```

All these statements do not do what you think because the types of these variables are originally `int`.

You are converting an `int` to `float` and assigning it back to `int`.

**Solution:**

Pass the values to a `float` rather than `int` to the function, implicit conversion will take care of the rest.

Change your function signature to

`double grade(float lc, float wc, float sc)`

Answer (score 2):

Or just do this (the other operands will not need the cast to `float` since it enough if only one of the operands is it, then the others will be converted to it implicitly)

```
double grade(int lc, int wc, int sc)
{
    float L = round(((float)wc/100)/lc);
    float S = round(((float)wc/100)/sc);
    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    return index;
}
```

Note that the return type is `double`, but you use just `float`s. Use `double` instead of `float`s in the function as types as well OR change return type to `float`.

The mistake is that this `wc = (float)wc;` is essentially this `wc = (int)(float)wc;` since `wc` type is `int`. Basically nothing happens, therefore when you make your calculation like `wc/100`, then this will be an integer division resulting in integer, so if `wc` is less than 100 (and >= 0), then the result is 0 and not a real number as you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

- `wc = (float)wc;` casts an `int` to a `float`, converts back to `int`, then assigns.  No real benefit here.
- `wc/100` is integer division, which discards the fraction of the quotient.  Not likely what OP wants.
- Converting `int` to `float` risks losing precision as so a less precise answer.  `double` is better for wide ranging `int` values.
- Code mixes uses of `float` and `double` with a call to a `double round(double)`, `double` multiplication and conversions from `float` to `double` to `float` to `double`.  Simplify and use `double` throughout.

---

```
double grade(int lc, int wc, int sc) {
    //               v------v `double` division 
    double L = round(wc/100.0/lc);
    double S = round(wc/100.0/sc);
    return 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
}
```